# Range of differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators

Show that the range of the operator $L$ is the whole space $C[a,b]$, and hence the inverse $L^{-1}$ has domain C[a,b].

$L:u \rightarrow -u''+p(x)u'+q(x)u$

$u \in dom(L)= \{u\in C^{2}[a,b], u(a)=0, u'(a)=0 \} $

Answer (score 2):

Showing that $\text{ran} L=C[a,b]$ is equivalent to showing that, for each $f\in C[a,b]$, $Lu=f$ has a solution $u$ satisfying $u(a)=u'(a)=0$. But $Lu=f$ is a second order linear DE which has a unique solution $u$ for $\forall f\in C[a,b]$. Done.

Comment: Ok, but how do we know that we can't extend our space?

Comment: Extend the space to which space? $L^2$? In this case, you need weak solutions.

Comment: Otherwise. Are we sure that we will not beyond C space?

Comment: If you want to study weak solutions, you need $L^2[a,b]$. Note that $C[a,b]$ is dense in $L^2[a,b]$.

Comment: So if i want to get a bigger range I have to change my domain?

Comment: It depends what kind of solutions you want.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answers.